# Match URLs containing subdomains

Tags: java, python, regex

I want the following regular expression to match URLs containing sub-domains but not match URLs without subdomains:

```
"^https?://(?:www\.)?(.*\.lexpress\.fr).*"
```

i.e match:

```
http://blah.lexpress.fr/whatever/test.html
```

do not match:

```
http://www.lexpress.fr/whatever/test.html
```

I tried in both Java and Python and BOTH URLs are matched - why is this so and how do I need to change the expression to only match the first one.

Thank you,

/David

Comment: www is a subdomain.  Do you just want to capture any url that doesn't start with www?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^https?://((?!www\.).*\.lexpress\.fr).*')
m = p.match('https://www.lexpress.fr')
print m
>>> None 
m = p.match('https://abc.lexpress.fr')
print m.group()
>>> 'https://abc.lexpress.fr.com'
```

Comment: This won't match `https://subwww.lexpress.fr`; e.g. any valid subdomain that *ends* with `www`.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [negative look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
"^https?://(?!www\.)(.*\.lexpress\.fr).*"
```

This matches any string that *does not have* `www.` after the `://` characters.

Python demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> subdomain = re.compile(r"^https?://(?!www\.)(.*\.lexpress\.fr).*")
>>> subdomain.match('http://www.lexpress.fr') is None
True
>>> subdomain.match('http://lexpress.fr') is None
True
>>> subdomain.match('http://subdomain.lexpress.fr').groups()
('subdomain.lexpress.fr',)
>>> subdomain.match('https://nested.subdomain.lexpress.fr').groups()
('nested.subdomain.lexpress.fr',)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
^(http[s]?://)?(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|ca|co.uk|com.au|fr|gov|br)\\?[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]*$
```

you can match any url 
as we can test in: [test regex here](http://tools.lymas.com.br/regexp_br.php#)

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for, this will match any domain starting with `www.`..